# PHP how to use Foreach loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops, foreach

I want a teacher to select multiple classes when he click a button, the classes are selected from the database and displayed via an  tag. I have made a function which makes a new select and displays another list of the classes, however my foreach loop doesn't seem to work...

Here's my JQuery which is inside a 'script' tag in the HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><select name="klas" style="width:40%;"><?php foreach ($klas as $klas) {echo "<option  value='".$klas->getCode()."'>".$klas->getCode()."</option>"; } ?></select><a href="#" class="remove_field">Verwijder</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

This is the button and the corresponding div's:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button type="button" class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div>
<select name="klas">
<?php foreach ($klas as $klas) {
echo "<option  value='".$klas->getCode()."'>".$klas->getCode()."</option>"; } ?>
</select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does someone have any idea how I can achieve the same result from JQuery as from the regular php/html select box?

Comment: @AthMav this is neither helpful nor related to the question

Comment: Where do you include your js? Did you <script src="script.php> <-- note the .php

Comment: @Jonasw the JS is a <script> tag inside the HTML, I should've noted that.

Comment: @Deus777 have tried entering different values and echo'ing/print'ing values but still got no result, the foreach loop simply does not get the value. Even though it does work in PHP

Comment: do you return value from `getCode()` ?? or do you simply echo it there?

Comment: If it works in PHP alone, are you sure that php is processed in html in your configuration?

Comment: @Deus777 it's getting echo'd

Comment: Try to return it, since you are using the result in string concatenation anyway

Comment: @Deus777 Still no result...

Comment: @sebas2201 see my answer below, found the problem

Answer (score 0):

**put your array in arr format in this answer and append to the div wherever you want on page currently i use select_div**

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button type="button" class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
        <div id ="select_div">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = [
      {val : 1, text: 'One'},
      {val : 2, text: 'Two'},
      {val : 3, text: 'Three'}
    ];

    var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('#select_div');

    $(arr).each(function() {
     sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });
    sel.append("</select>")
    </script>
```

Comment: I have tried different options on this one but still won't work for me

Comment: Try use bold text only as highlightin of a **specific part** of your answer, not the entire answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_(typography)

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Your problem is that you use the same value name for both `$klas` array as well as internal `foreach` variable. While this is not technically incorrect, notice that after  `foreach` `$klas` variable will be equal to last element of the array - **not the array itself**.

Since you were using this loop inside javascript it was tough to spot, and local test with `foreach` showed that everything is fine.

Anyway please update your code (everywhere were it is used) from:

```
<?php 
    foreach ($klas as $klas) { 
        $klas->getCode()
    }
?>
```

to

```
<?php 
    foreach ($klas as $k) {
        $k->getCode();
    }
 ?>
```